# javascript file is not loading and stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString also not executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I  have an application where I am downloading an html file from server and showing it in a `uiwebview`,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[dictionary valueForKey:@"htmlfilename"]];

NSError *err;
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];

[self.webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

Like this, After that in `Didfinishload` I am loading one JS file which is added in my application bundle like this

```
NSString *javaScript=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

After that on a button click I am calling `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`, but it's not working. Even that javascript file itself is not loading. Can anybody guide me on this ?

Comment: you should use javascript swift or objective c bridge framework or library for this , which is used by PayUMoney Webview

Comment: could you share the content of foo.js? Perhaps that code is only declaring function, but not calling them?

Comment: You may get better answers if you explain more. "it's not working" does not tell us much. You say that "that javascript file itself is not loading", but how do you know? I assume you're talking about the second javascript file that loads on button press. But you don't show that code. What have you tried to determine what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: @fishinear i put an alert on the js method on the file as alert(''Hi"),that itself is not happening means that JS file is not properly loaded, since there is nothing else in that methode

Answer (score 0):

You should try using JavaScriptCore Framework to work with JavaScript within Native iOS. This Framework gives access to WebKit's JavaScript Engine. Earlier this framework supported MAC but now  it has support to iOS and enables interoperatability between swift/objective-c as well as javascript. For further reference read this link below.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/124075/javascriptcore-tutorial

This is my thought based on the understanding of your question. But if you have more details, i have try to offer other solutions.

Happy Coding!